# GUI program with toggable console?

Tags: python, console, terminal, pythonw

I've seen some apps allow you to show/hide the console when you need to read log messages. For example Blender3D allows that (blender.org).

I was wondering if this can be done in Python and how.

My main window is a Panda3D (panda3d.org) window.
I've read somewhere that one option is to hide the "real" console (pythonw) and create another console and just redirect everything from the "real" one to it, every time you want to "show" the "real" console. No idea *how* this can be done.

Or at least a way to choose whether to start the program with the console or without it by reading a configuration file or something.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your third paragraph. You can easily create a console-like window with nothing but a scrollbar and a text area, and you can, e.g. redirect `sys.stdout` to some object that appends to that window, and hide and show that window whenever you want. Is that what you're looking for? If so, which part of it do you need help with?

Comment: A "console-like" window or a console window, which I want? Sounds easy in words, how about showing me how simple the code is?

Comment: I said a "console-like window" intentionally. If you need it to be an actual console window, then creating a second one that you can hide and show is no simpler than hiding and showing the one you started with (unless you need Win9x compatibility… which you don't), so there is no reason to create a second one. So, does it have to actually _be_ a console window, or is a normal GUI window that looks and acts like a console window good enough?

Comment: If you _do_ need it to be an actual console window, keep in mind that a process can only have one console at a time. (You can, of course, create a child process with a different console. Or free your original console and alloc a new one. And that can be helpful when you're running inside python.exe under a cmd.exe or other process sharing the same console, but I don't see how it would help you here.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about Windows because this *console toggling* in blender is Windows exclusive. I'm guessing Blender uses [`GetConsoleWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows.

This is how you could do it in python with [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/):

```
import win32gui, win32console, win32api, win32con
import time

console_window = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
time.sleep(1)
win32gui.ShowWindow(console_window, win32con.SW_HIDE)
time.sleep(1)
win32gui.ShowWindow(console_window, win32con.SW_SHOW)
time.sleep(1)
```

If you run this program with python and not pythonw it will show the console, sleep for a second, hide the console, sleep for another second and then hide it again.

Mind that this code only works on Windows. On other platforms silly stuff like this is not necessary because if you want a program to show a console then you run it from the console.